# No angular view loads when there's just a # in the URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a navigation tool that always returns the URL like this when I'm in my angular app.

> http://example.com/pagename#

instead of

> http://example.com/pagename#/viewName

When the navigation is clicked, this results in my app not having any view loaded.  Otherwise, my routes work fine.

With my default route provider, it doesn't know how to handle this. I don't know if this is something I'm supposed to account for or what.

How can I adjust my route provider (or something else) to know how to handle when there's a # symbol in the URL without a path?

Here's a snippet of my route provider.

```
myApp.config(["$routeProvider", 
    function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
        .when("/itemUpdate", {
            templateUrl: "/path/update.html",
            controller: "itemUpdateController"
        })
        .when("/about", {
            templateUrl: "/path/about.html",
            controller: "aboutController"
        })
        .when("/items", {
            templateUrl: "/path/items.html",
            controller: "itemsController"
        })
        .when("/items/:itemId", {
            templateUrl: "/path/item.html",
            controller: "itemController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/about"
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: don't use `<a href="#">` in html. Likely what is causing it. Need more details if not

Comment: This question is tagged angular-ui-router, but it looks from your snippet like you're using ngRoute. It might be worth clarifying that (unless you're using angular-ui-router's [shim](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/26) over ngRoute).

Comment: does your console shows any log ? or else as @charlietfl mentioned, don't use <a href="#">, instead u can try using simple <a href>.

Comment: Sorry, I added the tags that SO suggested.  The link that's in the navigation is the raw URL.  Basically, what the first example in the post above shows, minus the #.

Comment: No, there's no errors, warnings, or anything else that appears to be related in the console window.